# ajax call not waiting

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that when my users click "submit", I first want to check if the username they have chosen is already taken. I use ajax for this:

```
function submit() {
    if (userNameTaken()) {
        alert("Please choose a username that is not already in use.");
        return false;
    }
}

function userNameTaken() {
    var taken = false;
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.get("username_used.cgi", { "username": username }, function(data) {
        taken = data > 0;
    });
    return taken;
}
```

So I know that when a username is taken, the function `userNameTaken()` does return true.

However, the form saves anyway almost as if the javascript does not pause and wait for this ajax call to finish, but instead continues to go on and evaluate. Any ideas on how to solve this so that my form will wait for this ajax call and not submit?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because the Ajax will not execute in normal top-down process. And submit will not wait for ajax response. you can use a `normal button` instead `submit button` so that you can submit the form manually.

```
<form ... >
// other parts

<input type="button" value="sumbit" onclick="userNameTaken();"/>
</form>
```

change the code as

```
function userNameTaken() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.get("username_used.cgi", { "username": username }, function(data) {
       if(data > 0){
          alert("Please choose a username that is not already in use.");
        }else{
            // validation goes here
           $('form').submit(); 
        }
    });
}
```

So it will check the ajax response and than submit the form if the usename not taken else show the alert. you can put some id to button and form to handle it easily using jquery..

Comment: And form will happily submit bypassing validation if user simply hits enter on any of the input fields.

Comment: You should be aware that submit works without submit button in any browser except for IE. Try it out http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/cdwqs/. The answer is relevant but seriously flawed. Never ever hang submit actions on the button. See section about clearly and dangerously incorrect answers in the link you posted.

Comment: :P thanks man but this event can be prevented easily by using keyup and preventDefault. moreover it doesn't matter as you can see that the answer was correct and helpful to OP.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return data from an Ajax call like this: Ajax calls return at arbitrary future times, while the call to `userNameTaken()` returns (essentially) immediately, certainly before the Ajax request completes.

You may make the call synchronous, at the risk of stalling the browser UI. IMO this is not preferred.

Alternatively, only allow submission if the name is unused: use the callback function to set an "ok" flag, or enable the submit button, or pop up the alert, or...

FWIW, I find popup alerts *very* disruptive and counter to a smooth UX.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "async" setting of Ajax call to "false". This will force the function to block until the call returns.

Here is a link to JQuery documentation. Check out the "async" setting:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @srchulo - You should know that if you set `async: false`, the browser will freeze for the duration of the ajax call and be unresponsive.  This is NOT the recommended practice.  The recommended practice is to change your code to process the results of the ajax call in the success handler only.  This requires a rethinking of how the code flow works, but makes a better user experience when done right.

Comment: i tried to something like that only.. but someone didnt like and down voted. I feel it can be done that way, pls have a look on my answer and give your view.